# EPPlus - Row Out Of Range exception

Tags: c#, datatable, epplus

I'm trying to import datatable with 1000000 records into Excel using EPPlus library.

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
var recordCount = dt.Rows.Count;
ws.Cells["A5"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
```

I'm getting `Row Out of Range` exception on `ws.Cells["A5"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);` line

It worked when I had 1000 records.

Is there row limit size when working with EPPlus?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel version is 2010

Comment: That will hold a million records.  Older versions only did 64K. EPPlus is not limited.  From a little googling, it might  be the ws.Cells["A5"] causing the error.

Comment: I am facing the similar "Row out of range" error while loading dataset of 1.5millions records in EPPLus.worksheet3.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(ds.Tables[0], true); Need help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

You probably tried to import a little bit more than 1.000.000 records. The maximum before throwing this exception is 1.048.576 (which exactly equals the maximum number of rows [specified](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmworksheetworkbook) for Excel version 2010).

Have a look at the source code:

The last line of the `LoadFromDataTable` method in [ExcelRangeBase.cs](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase.cs) returns the imported excelrange: `_worksheet.Cells[...]`

You can find the implementation of this indexer in [ExcelRange.cs](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelRange.cs) and there you'll see that the range is validated by `ValidateRowCol` (all the way at the bottom).

Finally, this validation throws the exception you mentioned when the requested row is larger than the MaxRows property of an excelpackage, which equals 1.048.576

Answer (score 5):

When you get "Row out of range", the row parameter is probably too high or too low.
Remember that it starts to count from 1.

Comment: I am facing the similar "Row out of range" error while loading dataset of 1.5millions records in EPPLus. worksheet3.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(ds.Tables[0], true); Need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: @AsifIqbal Did you figure it out? Did you try to count from 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had placed a list in a list. Should have been only a list and not a list in a list.

To be exact i created a list of object that I then placed in a list, parsed to JSON and loaded to a DataTable with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, jsonFormat). Then I got the error.